# How to change GCC long of Windows become 8 byte? Not Cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, long-integer

So this is the requirement asked by our professor, we need to use `c89` standard (there is no `long long` type). And in linux before compile we have to use `-ansi` flag.

**I prefer to debug in Windows first using VS Code**, however one day I notice long overflow then I just realised the long of gcc in x64 windows is 4 byte, in x64 linux gcc `long` is 8 byte.

1. I am very sure the installation that I've chosen is x86_64
2. How I knew it's 4 byte by running `printf("The size of long is: %d\n", (int)sizeof(long));`

Do I need to add any command line flag to gcc to make the size of `long` become 8bit?
What can I do to make the GCC reserve `long` as 8 byte?

Btw I open the header file and I saw this
[What is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qtTC.png)

`C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\_mingw.h`

I tried to change to

```
#ifndef __LP64__    /* 32 bit target, 64 bit Mingw target */
#define __int64 long
#else           /* 64 bit Cygwin target */
#define __LONG32 int
#endif
```

But it didn't work somehow

Comment: you don't want to make it 8-bit. The value you want is 8-byte

Comment: Windows uses 32-bit long.  Period.  If you want a different size, you need to use something other than windows, such as cygwin or WSL.  Trying to use a 64-bit long on plain windows will cause you all kinds of library incompatibility issues.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I tried Cygwin but Visual Studio code can't debug with it. It didn't display the output

Comment: @Eric: Hey, you could make a feature request to be able to debug Cygwin binaries. VSCode's got almost all of the required since it can remote debug from Windows to Linux already. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview

Answer (score 0):

To change `long` to 8 byte on windows, you need to use the Cygwin64 version of `gcc` rather than the `mingw` version. Microsoft set the model to LLP64 (that is, `long long` and `void *`) are 64 bit. You can't override this with mere compiler options as system linkage would fail. But Cygwin has its own linkage and provides 64 bit Unix compatibility where `sizeof(long)` = `sizeof(void *)`.

Source: https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/programming.html

We can almost do a `typedef` or `#define` thing, but `printf` format specifiers won't work very well.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion however I want to use it with Visual Studio Code. I can't use Cygwin. I can only debug windows executable

Comment: @Eric: Rebuilding the library stack in LP64 is too much work.

Comment: so you are implying it is not possible right? I am thinking if we can change the define of header of long become long long

Comment: @Eric: That's easy. Now printf format specifier, that's hard. How will you do printf("... %ld ...", (mylong)3);

Comment: no I mean change from Mingw32 header file so that it act long as long long (8byte)

Comment: @Eric VS Code and Cygwin have nothing to do with each other, one is a text editor and another is a runtime environment. And Windows executable use the Windows convention, you can't change that without breaking things unless you don't want to interact with the outside world and your program is tiny

Comment: yes it is a tiny program that is why I am not concern. You should comment above not here.